# What exactly is the definition of a voltage regulator?

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator, diodes, zener

I was assigned to design a voltage regulator for a secondary ECE circuits class, and I would like to know precisely how that element is defined, given the following.

- It has an input and an output
- The input voltage varies from 0V to 15V
- The output voltage <s>must</s> may vary between 9V and 11V
- The output cannot simply be connected to a constant voltage source, that's cheating
- Using a saturated Op-Amp is also cheating

I understand how to design a voltage regulator using zener diodes, my question is, WHY do I need to use them? What part of "Voltage regulator" implies that my other methods are cheating?

I received the following quote from my professor regarding it when I asked them, after showing them my circuit diagram, but it did not answer my real question. My circuit otherwise works, it fulfills the assigned requirement nicely.

"I can't tell how the circuit functions by just looking at it. A voltage regulator does not necessarily have to have a diode, but only an op-amp can't operate as a voltage regulator theoretically. "

Why can't it?

Here is an image of my circuit in P-Spice:

[image]

And its output from a DC sweep on Vin from 0V to 15V

[image]

Many thanks for any answers.

EDIT:
Here is the literal assignment, pasted verbatim.

Use zener diode, BJT or other components to design a voltage regulator that will provide an output voltage of 10 V (nominal value) to a variable load. The actual output voltage variation should be less than ±1V of the nominal value under the load variation from 500Ω to 5 kΩ and input voltage variation from 0 V to 15 V.

Comment: While this sort of works while the input voltage is 12V, how does it work when the input voltage is say 3?

Comment: Your U2A makes little sense. Right now it's used as an non-inverting amplifier with a gain of 100 thousand and 1.

Comment: @horta Does the image of the P-Spice plot not show? at 3V the output is approximately 10.1V, and can be tuned to whatever value is desired by adjusting the supply voltage on the Op-Amp. The 12V supply is not the input voltage, it just supplies the Op-Amp.

Comment: @Harry Svensson It is designed to have a monstrous gain so that it saturates immediately with very little input voltage. Also, is the gain not 1001 V/V? 1 + 10k/10?

Comment: Ah, I missed the horizontal axis. Where are you getting this extra 12V from? You're not regulating the input voltage, you're simply using a cheat 12V and dropping a small voltage drop through it to get your output. The input voltage doesn't really have anything to do with the output.

Comment: In your design, the output power comes from the op-amp power supply, not the Vin (and op-amps can't deliver much power).  A voltage regulator should pass power from the varying Vin to the output, and keep the output voltage fairly constant as Vin varies.  Look at a datasheet for a voltage regulator IC, such as the LM7805.

Comment: If I do not use additional power sources than how can I turn ~0V into 10V? I spoke with the professor and they said it was expected and practically required to use an amplifier with external power.

Comment: Boost converter could get you from a few voltages up to 10 V. Below a diode threshold voltage, that won't work though. If you require extra power, then there's not much point in voltage regulating this Vin voltage since you actually have your power coming from a different place. I would start questioning if your professor knows what a voltage regulator is actually used for.

Comment: It's possible your professor is referring to a voltage reference rather than a voltage regulator. Even then, a reference voltage that varies from 9 to 11V seems like a really bad Vref. Maybe he's just making it easier that way though.

Comment: @T.K. Oh, yeah you're right. 1001, I calculated the k twice for some reason. Either way, this is not the right solution. Imagine this as going to war with a sword, rather than a gun. Or running rather than taking the train to Moscow. Using an op-amp as a voltage regulator is a no no.

Comment: @Harry Svensson Perhaps my question was too broadly stated. I would specifically like to know WHY it is, as you put it, a no no. The circuit satisfies all design requirements OTHER than "being a voltage regulator" which is the part I don't get. I don't doubt that it is wrong, but I can't see why.

Comment: Start over with valid specs. You cannot get **any Vout with 0V in** unless a battery is involved with time and power specs. This obviously demands a buck:boost regulator. Work on better power specs, V,I,Z(t) and buck:boost topologies

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 But... I can't. I got the assignment, now I have to do it. If the assignment is not possible, then I will just have to fudge it the best I can. It's due tomorrow at noon.

Comment: Ask someone who understands if the assumption is that normal operation is intended to have Vout> Vin. This exercise is to teach you to learn how things work and what the limitations are. There are practical dynamic range issues for anything. But many requirements are unclear. Call the prof's assistant or the prof.   Anything is possible if you define exactly how it can work with real parts as long as it doesn't violate the laws of physics.  OP Amp gain is good for error feedback to regulate output by PWM or linear bias and this gives best regulation. Setpoint> ratio of output vs ref diode ...

Comment: Gee, I thought *voltage regulator* was a government bureaucrat that oversees power utilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that **it can't be done** given the current specs. There is currently no way you can get 0V regulated to 10V. The prof created incorrect input parameters, and he/she should correct these parameters before this can be solved at all.

If I were in your shoes, I'd follow the leading questions general direction and use a zener and a bjt to create a simple voltage regulator that will work as close as possible to the design parameters.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTfQIC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This will work approximately from 10.7V up to 15V. The reason I'd use a 10.7V zener is because there's an approximate 0.7V drop across the bjt. The zener volage gives us a reference voltage to work from. R1 is a current limiting resistor to prevent the zener from burning out. The BJT is setup in an emitter-follower/common-collector amplifier topology. This has a tendency to "pin" the emitter 0.7 volts below the base voltage. This allows much higher current to flow to the output than if you used a zener/resistor combo alone. Note that you could make this even better if you switched out the BJT for an op-amp using negative feedback to pin the output voltage to the zener reference voltage. This would be my best attempt at your nebulous homework question.

The entire point of a voltage regulator is to take a potentially variable input voltage without any other power supplies and regulate it **down** to a consistent value.

Comment: I believe that the intention was to use an amplifier to increase the voltage first, then drop it again to 10V. This is my best guess, and based on that, this answer is the most useful for posterity.

Comment: Then dont accept this answer and look at Buck-boost regulators

Answer (score 1):

When we say "voltage regulator" we usually mean a circuit that produces a fixed output voltage, regardless of the current drawn by the load, or the power supply voltage provided to it.

A circuit that produces an output voltage proportional (or varying in response to) a control input voltage is not a voltage regulator, it's an amplifier.

> The input voltage varies from 0V to 15V

This is a strange requirement for a (linear) voltage regulator. Normally the only input is the power supply, and we require the power supply voltage to be higher than the output voltage (for a positive regulator). So for 11 V output, you might require the input voltage be at least 11.5 V or even at least 15 V.

> The output voltage must vary between 9V and 11V

This is a very strange requirement for a voltage regulator, unless the output voltage is to be set once (for example by a choice of resistors connected to the circuit) and then kept constant whenever the circuit is used.

> Using a saturated Op-Amp is also cheating

Using a saturated op-amp isn't cheating, it just generally won't work, since once the op-amp is saturated its output voltage depends strongly on the power supply voltage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @The Photon. The load resistance does vary in addition, from 500 to 5k ohms. We are expected to use some amplification to get from ~0V to 10V. The saturated Op-Amp certainly LOOKS like it's constant across the input voltage sweep. Note that I am not using the input to supply the Op-Amp.

Comment: @T.K., that is a usual requirement for a regulator, but it's more often expressed in terms of the current that will be drawn by the resistor (or other load).

Answer (score 0):

A voltage regulator needs a reference voltage, a pass transistor or similar device, and a feedback circuit that drives the output to a voltage related to the reference.

In other words, in control terms, there is an internally generated setpoint (the reference) an actuator (the pass transistor) and a controller (the feedback amplifier and any compensation required to get desirable dynamic performance).

You are showing a saturated op-amp which isn't regulating anything- it's just outputting the supply voltage minus an internal voltage drop.

The reference in an IC regulator is often a bandgap type circuit, but for a non-integrated design you can use a zener diode. An op-amp by itself can only supply limited current and does not have any reference voltage so it can only work with an externally supplied signal.

Comment: Thanks @Spehro Pefhany, But regulation can't get me from 0V to 10V, and If i'm already using an amplifier, why not simply saturate it and let it be the output? At least according to P-Spice, it works.

Comment: Because it is not "regulating", it's simply passing the power supply voltage to the output (minus something). A regulator will accept input voltage changing from 11V to 15V and the output will stay at 10V +/-0.1V, say.

Comment: that makes sense, but then how is the assignment even possible? This all seems a little off...

Comment: The prof want you to design a regulator. He or she has attempted to exclude certain things that are certainly not regulators so you won't as likely get a failing mark for producing something that is not a regulator (like your schematic). I don't see any problem here.

Comment: The input voltage varies from _0V_ to 15V. How can I get an output voltage higher than my input voltage without using external supplies, like an amplifier?

Comment: @T.K., Is it possible that "input voltage" means _control_ input?  That is, is the prof asking you to design an _adjustable_ voltage regulator?

Comment: @jameslarge Decide for yourself. The entirety of the assignment specification is at the end of the question. I don't _think_ this is what was meant though.

Comment: Okay, I see your issue then, if those are the actual words. A linear regulator would only be expected to work with an input voltage at least a bit above the output voltage.

Answer (score 0):

What part of "Voltage regulator" implies that my other methods are cheating?

Nothing. per se.

But impedance is never 0 for a voltage source and Op Amps are only near ideal only when the currents are within spec. and BJT types all have at least 2 diode drop saturation limits. The outputs and inputs must be in the linear operating range. All parts have resistance even capacitors and chokes. These cannot be ignored when it comes to details with power loss. But you can start simple by reading how it's done.

Failure to follow these simple rules, results in design failure.

So it's not cheating *"per se"*. It just won't work.

[image]

(ref Wiki)

But all power supply regulation specs are defined as ;

- **Error tolerance**, which implies a stable reference + tolerance stackup
- **Load regulation error** which implies a source/load impedance ratio worst case

  - these are impacted by non-ideal switch RdsOn and/or BJT saturation voltage @ I rated.
- **supply sensitivity error** , which implies loop gain error and design current effects on inductor useful range for ΔVin/ΔVout and ΔI
- **Environmental error** which implies all parts have thermal coefficients of resistance, voltage or current limits as a function of temperature rise above ambient

So there must be a total error budget from each of these terms to make a good spec and a great design.  With this, we can make crude assumptions then verify from experience testing it.

Using ideal parts will result in less than ideal actual results so we add non-ideal values of Rs or DCR or ESR for RdsOn, L and C must be added to any simulation from the component specs or use recommended parts from OEM.

**If the specification is relaxed to some minimum V instead of 0 , the output/input range implies a voltage gain >1 and < 1 so a boost+buck combination SMPS is essential and a linear regulator is not possible.**

Hint: [Search engine "images"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=buck%20boost%20regulators&client=firefox-b-ab&dcr=0&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjhY6D8oLYAhWQ14MKHYkQAXIQ_AUICigB&biw=1696&bih=829) gives tons of ideas for any topic , some good , some bad. It depends who did it and what key words **you select.**